# Ranger file manager - Open gnome-terminal instead of xterm

Tags: linux, environment-variables, gnome-terminal, xterm, file-manager

I recently started using Ranger as my default file manager, and I'm really enjoying it. Right now, I've managed to change rifle.conf so that when I play audio or video from Ranger, mpv opens in a new xterm window and the media starts to play.

However, if possible, I would like Ranger to open the gnome-terminal instead of xterm. In `/.config/ranger/rifle.conf`, it says that using the `t` flag will run the program in a new terminal:

`If $TERMCMD is not defined, rifle will attempt to extract it from $TERM`

I tried setting `$TERMCMD` in both my .profile and .bashrc files, but even though `echo $TERMCMD` would print "gnome-terminal", Ranger would still open xterm. I also messed with setting `$TERM` to "gnome-terminal", but that was messy and I decided to leave it alone.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of 2017, the source-code ([runner.py](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/blob/master/ranger/core/runner.py#L197)) did this:

```
        term = os.environ.get('TERMCMD', os.environ.get('TERM'))
        if term not in get_executables():
            term = 'x-terminal-emulator'
        if term not in get_executables():
            term = 'xterm'
        if isinstance(action, str):
            action = term + ' -e ' + action
        else:
            action = [term, '-e'] + action
```

so you should be able to put any xterm-compatible program name in `TERMCMD`.  However, note the use of `-e` (gnome-terminal doesn't match xterm's behavior).  If you are using Debian/Ubuntu/etc, the Debian packagers have attempted to provide a wrapper to hide this difference in the `x-terminal-emulator` feature.  If that applies to you, you could set `TERMCMD` to `x-terminal-emulator`.

Followup - while the design of the `TERMCMD` feature has not changed appreciably since mid-2016, the location within the source has changed:

- [Refactor and improve the TERMCMD handling](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/commit/058a7ebe563e4c30ff9bd15b2861c1f86df7d23b#diff-cc5478eddc22308e8e4a50aff879aa80)  moved it to [ranger/ext/get_executables.py](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/commit/058a7ebe563e4c30ff9bd15b2861c1f86df7d23b#diff-c8ac4efefa619d12259dc51df3baa984)

That is implemented in [`get_term`](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/blob/1687e0f41f172cef6923f75f4c6f1038f19671dc/ranger/ext/get_executables.py#L53):

```
def get_term():
    """Get the user terminal executable name.
    Either $TERMCMD, $TERM, "x-terminal-emulator" or "xterm", in this order.
    """
    command = environ.get('TERMCMD', environ.get('TERM'))
    if shlex.split(command)[0] not in get_executables():
        command = 'x-terminal-emulator'
        if command not in get_executables():
            command = 'xterm'
    return command
```

which uses `x-terminal-emulator` as before.

There is a *related* use of `TERMCMD` in [`rifle.py`](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/blob/720e3fd798caa2f8bfd0a19fd9ed5c0eab5dd14c/ranger/ext/rifle.py#L357), used for executing commands rather than (as asked in the question) for opening a terminal.  Either way, the key to using ranger is `x-terminal-emulator`, since GNOME Terminal's developers do not document their command-line interface, while Debian developers have provided this workaround.

Quoting from [Bug 701691 – -e accepts only one term; all other terminal emulators accept more than one term](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=701691) (which the developer refused to fix, marking it "not a bug"):

> Christian Persch 2013-06-06 16:02:54 UTC
>
> There are no docs for the gnome-terminal command line options.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the `x-terminal-emulator feature` - that solve my issue.

Comment: that doesn't work for me. I'm on Manjaro and ranger doesn't launch gnome-terminal for me.

Comment: No, rifle.py is used for opening a terminal, and get_term() just gives the terminal name which is not the problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm now pretty sure that `runner.py` is irrelevant. `rifle.py` is the file to change.

At around line 375, there is a line:

```
cmd = [os.environ['TERMCMD'], '-e'] + cmd
```

Should try to change the `'-e'` flag to something else, depending on what your $TERMCMD is. I've tested a few different terminals and these are working for me:

- gnome-terminal: change to `'--'` or `'-x'`
- xfce4-terminal: `'-x'`
- lxterminal: `'-e'`
- mate-terminal: `'-x'`
- terminator: `'-x'`

I haven't checked others, but it will probably be one of `'--'`, `'-e'`, `'-x'`.